# Is it possible to rent a car on Île des Pins in New Caledonia?

Tags: car-rentals, islands, new-caledonia

Using a worryingly large slug of hotel loyalty points, I've just booked a two night stay on [Île des Pins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isle_of_Pines_%28New_Caledonia%29) in New Caledonia, which is often called *l'île la plus proche du paradis* (the island the closest to paradise!). At the very least I need to get from the airport to the hotel and back, but possibly I'll want to spend a few hours each day looking round part of the island. For that, I'll really need a car, so I can get to beaches like this one:

[image: Île des pins - Baie de Kanumera, by MickaelT from www.flickr.com/photos/mickaeltr/3445895909/]

Normally when I want to hire a car, I check with a couple of the bigger companies, check with some of the brokers, and book what seems the best deal. Unfortunately, none of the major chains seem to have an office there, and all of the brokers keep trying to give me cars in Nouméa, on a different island!

Is it possible to hire a car on Ile de Pins? And if so, what's the process?

Comment: Île des Pins is a tiny island which is pretty much dedicated to tourism. You won't find any car rental chain there, only hotels renting a few cars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some travel pages that give more details. [Lonely planet says](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/new-caledonia/ile-des-pins/transport/getting-around):

> The hotel or gîte where you are staying should be able to arrange airport or wharf transfers. Some of them also hire scooters and cars, and can arrange island tours (around 1700 CFP per person). Hôtel Kou-Bugny and Gîte Nataiwatch hire scooters (3200/4700 CFP per half-/full-day). Along with Hôtel Kodjeue, they also hire cars (7000 CFP per day Monday to Friday, 8500 CFP Saturday and Sunday). Rates are generally cheaper if you are a guest at the hotel or gîte. Rates include airport and wharf drop-offs and pick-ups, as well as petrol. Relais Le Kuberka hires cars to guests only.